# LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy being reset to 0 at boot

Tags: windows, security, windows-server-2016, amazon-ami

I am trying to use the Windows 2016 STIG AMI from Amazon with Packer. I am able to get WinRM to successfully work by setting the LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy setting to 1 (disabled), but as soon as I do a reboot, it goes back to 1 (enabled). I would think that the same registry key I am changing is what the MS Security Policy ADMX template is derived from? Could there be another location or setting somewhere that tells Group Policy to disable this policy?

I am looking at the same error posted here. I tried using Procmon to monitor the registry key, but I can't seem to find where Windows is getting the true desired value of the registry key.

Answer (score 0):

Group Policy settings will always override registry key values, regardless of whether they are applied via local policies or domain policies. In this case, the Windows 2016 STIG AMI is most likely making use of the supplemental ADMX files from the Windows Server 2016 security baseline (which can be downloaded as a part of the Microsoft Security Compliance Toolkit).

To check this, run `gpedit.msc` and navigate to the following policy setting:

**Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > MS Security Guide:
Apply UAC restrictions to local accounts on network logons**

In the current version of the SCT, this group of settings comes from the `SecGuide.admx` and `SecGuide.adml` files.

Your question does not specify whether the server is joined to a domain, so I'll recommend that you keep both local policy *and* domain group policy in mind. To see what is actually applied, you can run `rsop.msc` on the server or, from the command line: `gpresult.exe /H GPReport.html && GPReport.html`.

Be aware that changes to these settings *may* take you out of compliance with STIGs *if* you are required to follow that baseline.

Comment: Is there anyway to change those programmatically? I am using packer to make an image and need winrm to work after reboot

Comment: Will the deployed images be joined to an AD domain?